# Where is the link to get from the new chat page back to meta/parent site?

Tags: support, chat

I clicked over to the new third place from the banner on the parent site (which is cool btw). But I couldn't find a link back to either meta or RPG.se itself. There was a logo in the upper left that says "Role-Playing Games Beta" but that returned me to chat.RPG.se when clicked.

Did I miss something? Or this intentional?

(It also appears that MSO's chat does the same thing so maybe this is a question for MSO.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logo in the upper left of the **All Rooms** chat landing page

> [image: chat landing page link back to parent site]

now links back to the parent site like I expected it to.

Answer (score 2):

The logo is at the lower right (next to your chat box) and should take you back.

Comment: Thanks! I see that one now that I've entered a room. My question arose from the page you land on with the different rooms. I guess it still seems like the upper left logo is misleading and it is weird to me to need to enter a room to leave the chat area :).

Comment: No problemo, I owed ya one!